# Ardour 3 and Superior Drummer

Tags: ardour

Is it possible to have Ardour3 working with Superior Drummer 2.0 ?

I own an Alessis DM10, just wanted to start playing with midi and superior drummer. 
Another enviroment is welcome too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Install airwave manager (https://github.com/phantom-code/airwave)
- Open airwave, create a new link
- Show airwave where is located the superior drummer dll (vst plugin location)
- Show airwave where it can make the bridge, choose a folder where your DAW can locate the VST bridge (link location).
- Choose a name for a bridge.
- Click OK and close Airwave manager
- Go to your DAW and go the settings part where you can set a path to VST's. Just set the same path you set on "link location" on airwave.
- Your DAW should now find the VST and identify it as a LXVST (linux vst).

But you also may want to set your system with wine-rt so the plugin can work on realtime.

Comment: OMG, sorry guys!
didn't see the date on the post :(

Answer (score 0):

Superior Drummer 2.0 is a VST I believe, so it would have to be compiled for linux. Which I don't think it is.

Answer (score 0):

*Superior Drummer* is a VST and only available for Windows or OS X platforms. The developers do not support native Linux. With *Ardour 3*, VST support is available, however, as the VST is a Windows binary, it will be running under *Wine*, which the VST may not run entirely correctly under. This also assumes that the Windows VST support was compiled and installed in the package.

For an open source drum machine, you can install the *hydrogen* package. *Hydrogen* works with *JACK* as well, and can easily be recorded from inside *Ardour*.